# How to create a safe non-global Mutex for forms launched asynchronously

Tags: c#, winforms, mutex

**Requirement:**

**A.** 1 user login can open 0-1 `System.Windows.Form` instances on 1 physical machine in `ProcessName`.
**B.** 2 different user logins are each able to open 0-1 `System.Windows.Form` instances on 1 physical machine in `ProcessName`. 
**C.** `MutexChecker` is in its own class rather than a member of `Form` because the responsibility for  disposing of the Mutex changes from one form to a different form based on user actions.
**D.** Said `Form`'s are launched asynchrously after the creation of the Mutex.  So I cannot implement a `using` statement.

**Problem:**

On other SO posts, I've seen code similar to the below labeled as "unsafe".  However, the reasons for the code being labeled "unsafe" are not given.  Rather, a [global mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567) is offered as the solution.  A global mutex works machine-wide, therefore it does not meet the requirement.

**What I have tried:**

Call `mutexChecker.RunCheck()` from said `System.Windows.Form`

```
public class MutexChecker:IDisposable
{
    private Mutex mutex;

    public bool RunCheck()
    {
        bool createdNew;
        mutex = new Mutex(initiallyOwned: true, name: "AppName", createdNew: out createdNew);

        if (!createdNew)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("AppName is already running.  Please complete the other note before opening a new window.");
        }

        return createdNew;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();//ERROR: safe handle has been disposed
        mutex.Dispose();//Does not always release the mutex for some unknown reason
    }
```

Dispose on the mutex during `Form.Dispose`.

**Question**

How can I safely create a mutex that fulfills the requirement?

Comment: P Brian Mackey look at this stackoverflow post and see the Accepted Answer on this page you should be able to copy paste the working answer to fit your needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340043/how-to-run-one-instance-of-a-c-sharp-winform-application

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I clarified the question.  I don't believe that will work for reasons in the update.

Comment: Is it a stupid suggestion to use (global) mutex, and make them pseudo-local by using the user id as part of the mutex name? This would make sure different user ids can open 0-1 instances on one physical machine. (Of course, you´d need an additional (global, and rightly so!) mutex or semaphore to make sure a maximum logged-in user count is not exceeded.

Comment: Just append the user name to the mutex name.  Your code crashes when you dispose more than once, use a *disposed* variable.  And don't call ReleaseMutex when you didn't acquire it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to handle multiple forms dealing with disposal of my `Mutex` in an asynchronous fashion, I raise an `event` to designate the time of disposal.  Otherwise, I just dump the unecessary mutex immediately after construction:

```
public class MutexChecker
{
    private Mutex mutex;
    private const string instanceName = "AppName";
    private bool createdNew = false;

    public bool RunCheck()
    {            
        mutex = new Mutex(initiallyOwned: true, name: instanceName, createdNew: out createdNew);

        if (createdNew)
        {
            HelperClass.shutdown += Dispose;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("AppName is already running.  Please complete the other note before opening a new window.");
            mutex.Dispose();//dump...I don't need this instance
        }

        return createdNew;
    }

    void Dispose()
    {
        HelperClass.shutdown -= Dispose;
        mutex.Dispose();        
    }
}
```