# Accessing the exe file from asp.net mvc concurrently

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi i'm creating an application in which i have to call the exe file as a process from mvc.I was able to achieve it but the problem is when multiple request to the exe file comes how to handle it.If the exe file starts executing it may take 1 hour to complete its task.Meanwhile how to handle the other request to the exe?

Comment: What about calling the exe asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below two links it should solve your problem. Also you can queue the requests (might require implematation) so that launch the processes in queue later on.

[Ensuring only one application instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486195/ensuring-only-one-application-instance)

[How to run one instance of a c# WinForm application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340043/how-to-run-one-instance-of-a-c-sharp-winform-application)

Comment: My problem is i have use the exe process between multiple request simultaneously.

Comment: Every web request would be processed seperately and thus the exe will be launched for every web request. Unless the exe accesses some resource which it will lock there shouldn't be any problem.